# Cocos2D-X CCTransition shows background between the 2 scenes

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I've been trying to successfully create a slide transition between 2 scenes for the past 2 hours and all I can find are just some answers in Objective-C and I have no idea how to translate them.

I'm using XCode 5 with Cocos2D-X 2.2.3 to develop for iOS.

```
CCTransitionSlideInT *trans = CCTransitionSlideInT::create(1.0, Scene2::scene());
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(trans);
```

Doing that makes my current scene slide down and gets replaced by black (background) THEN after the transition is done, the second scene appears without any transition effects; it just appears.

How can I slide the first scene with the second one attached to it?
I've seen that it's done in TestCPP. I tried tracing it but it got too complicated for me. All I really need is some clarification!

Thanks in advance! And I hope I provided all the necessary info.

Comment: Have you missed something? Bcz I checked it, it worked perfectly for me (COCOS2D-X 2.2.1). One more thing are you creating UI in onEnterTransitionDidFinish method.. if you are it may making the problem.

Comment: I don't think I've missed anything. Although, I believe this problem occurs because the CCTransitionSlide method moves the scenes first then initializes the targeted scene. Which is why the first scene slides down perfectly but the second isn't rendered/initialized yet. I may be wrong, though...